# Exit Codes from system() not as expected

Tags: c, linux, freebsd

The system() function seems to be returning 128 times the exit code I get from the process it's evoking.

From the man page:

> RETURN VALUE
>          The  value  returned  is  -1  on  error  (e.g., fork(2)
>          failed), and the return status of  the  command  other‐
>          wise.

Here is what I've got.

```
$ ls tinker.c
tinker.c
$ echo $?
0
$ ls notexisting
ls: cannot access notexisting: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
$ cat tinker.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", system("ls tinker.c"));
    printf("%d\n", system("ls notexisting"));
    return 0;
}
$ gcc tinker.c -o tinker
$ ./tinker 
tinker.c
0
ls: cannot access notexisting: No such file or directory
512
```

The first call indicates that I'm not getting failures but the return codes look nothing like what I'm reading from the man page.  What'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From POSIX [`system(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter **in the format specified by waitpid()**.

To get the return code, you need to use the `WEXITSTATUS` macro.

Answer (score 4):

Your citation of the system man page misses the relevant part:

> ... This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2). 
>   Thus, the exit code of the command will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).

You need to right shift the return value by 8 (at least on Linux), to get the commands exit code.

The portable approach is to just use the macro itself.

Answer (score -2):

0 and 512 are the **termination status of the command**.

If the command executes successfully, it returns a 0 value, otherwise, it returns a non-zero value. And this non-zero value is various in different OSs. In my mac os, the return value of the second `system` command is 256.

You can also get answer from this question [`ls` exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010939/ls-exit-status).

Comment: "*0 and 512 are the termination status of the command.*" not necessarily. Please see the other answers the reasoning.